# Active Gitlab CI job only when early job was failed

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, pipeline, jobs

I was wondering and could not find a solution to our problem.

We have many CI pipelines running in scheduled times and we need to add a job in case of early job failure.

For example lets say that in the attached picture job "deploy-job1" failed (not like in the picture)
We want to have a "sleeping job" that will be activated and run only when a previous job did not succeed.

[Gitlab pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFABc.png)

Are there any suggestions on a way to handle this kind of a task?

We have tried handle this within the scripts we are running but we want to have general "sleeping job" that will be similar to all stages

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help:

```
.sleeping_job:
  needs: deploy-job1
  when: on_failure
  # do stuff
```

Comment: Is it possible to run this job when specific jobs fails?
Like let's say only when build1 fails

Comment: You should have `allow_failure: true` for the first job that runs (in this case `deploy-job1`) so that the whole pipeline doesn't fail after it.

Comment: Hi @amirhossein , I think I need to make it more clear.
I **DO** wish the rest of the pipeline to stop running in case of failure and only the sleeping job to be activate once the pipeline crushes at specific points.

So if `deploy-job1` fails, `deploy-job1-failure` will be **activate.**
Or if `test-job1` fails, `test-job1-failure` will be **activate**.

Comment: @Amirnazary `allow_failure: true` doesn't pass success/fail state onto subsequent jobs in the pipeline - so you can't have the control structure OP is looking for.